# Bivariate Hermite Polynomials

Tags: special-functions

I know I can get the Hermite polynomials in a single variable with: `HermiteH[n, x]`

Now I need the bivariate Hermite polynomials.
I thought about building them with this procedure:

```
basis = Flatten[TensorProduct[x^Range[0, n], y^Range[0, n]]]
orthbasis = Orthogonalize[basis, Integrate[Exp[-x^2 - y^2]*#1*#2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}] &]
```

Is this procedure correct? Or is there a better way with internal Mathematica functions like HermiteH, without involving Gram-Schmidt?

Comment: What about a product basis: H[n,x] H[m,y]

Comment: @DanielHuber does it provide a complete orthogonal basis? If yes, I think it should do.

Comment: As Hermite polynomials are a orthogonal basis on R, so is the product H[n,x] H[m,y] on R^2.

Comment: The products are separable so yes, they will be orthogonal.

Comment: "bivariate Hermite polynomials" - do you have a literature reference for how these are defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normal Hermite polynomial can be derived from the generating function
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!}H_n(x)=e^{2tx-t^2}.
$$
Analogically, bivariate Hermite polynomial are obtained from$$
\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{s^m}{m!}\frac{t^n}{n!}H_{m,n}(x,y)
=e^{sx+ty-s t}.
$$
Thus, in order to obtain $H_{m,n}(x,y)$ just do series expansion

```
H[m_, n_] := 
 SeriesCoefficient[
  SeriesCoefficient[Exp[s x + t y - s t], {s, 0, m}], {t, 0, n}]
H[3, 4]
(*1/144 (-24 y + 36 x y^2 - 12 x^2 y^3 + x^3 y^4)*)
```

Notice that $H_{m,n}(x,y)$ is not a direct product of two independent single-variable Hermite polynomials.

Bivariate Hermite polynomials also satisfy orthogonality relation, which can be found in Ismail, M., 2016. *[Analytic properties of complex Hermite polynomials](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2016-368-02/S0002-9947-2015-06358-2/)*. Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, 368(2), pp.1189-1210:
$$
\frac1\pi\frac{1}{m!n!}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}H_{m,n}(x+iy,x-iy)H^*_{p,q}(x+iy,x-iy)e^{-x^2-y^2}dxdy=\delta_{m,p}\delta_{n,q}
$$

Comment: More completely, `H[m_Integer?NonNegative, n_Integer?NonNegative][x_, y_] := SeriesCoefficient[Exp[s x + t y - s t], {s, 0, m}, {t, 0, n}]`

Comment: One remark: it seems to me that only some of those polynomials are orthogonal (I expected them to be all orthogonal). E.g. `Integrate[H[4, 0]*H[1, 1] Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]` gives `-(Pi/32)`.

Comment: @EnricoDetoma I extended my answer to provide source of information on the orthogonality relation.

Comment: @yarchik Thank you very much for the complete reference!